# Windows 10 update error every time Windows 7 updates

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, updates

Windows 7 machine, declined to update to Windows 10 when they were offering the free upgrades.

Ever since, every time Windows 7 tries to update, it takes forever to shut down and reboot (just now was over an hour) - I think it is because part of an update fails and it reverts but eventually, when I get back in, I am presented with this.

[image: Windows 10 install failure in Windows 7 update]

I can't for the life of me figure out which update this is bolted into or how to prevent this from happening every time it tried to update.

The two updates that Windows 7 currently says are available are KB2987107 and KB2813347. Every time I have tried to search for solutions, articles online refer to updates that I don't even have (available or installed).

Has anyone any ideas what I can do to stop this from repeatedly happening because I am losing many hours worth of time each week currently.

Comment: Have you searched the Internet for that error code Windows Update is returning?

Comment: Yes, many times now and I have tried various things that I found by searching to no avail but most scenarios of others reporting the error code are from users who were genuinely trying to update to Windows 10. And this I do not want to do.